# In the derivation of the normal formula, why, for $\frac{f'(y)}{yf(y)}$ to equal $\frac{f'(x)}{xf(x)}$, must both be a single constant?

Tags: calculus, probability

In acadelivery's video ["Normal distribution's probability density function derived in 5min" (via YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebewBjZmZTw), the guy explains in the middle of the derivation of the normal formula that, for $\frac{f'(y)}{yf(y)}$ to be equal to $\frac{f'(x)}{xf(x)}$, both need to be a single constant.

I edit my question, since  my doubt is why couldn´t they take more values? How do we make that immediate conclusion that for all $x$ and $y$ the fractions before don't change ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's choose an $x_0$ where that ratio is defined. Then, $$\frac{f'(x_0)}{x_0f(x_0)}=C$$ is just a number. Since the given relationship is valid for all $x$ and $y$, you know that for all $y$ values $$\frac{f'(y)}{yf(y)}=\frac{f'(x_0)}{x_0f(x_0)}=C$$
You can now rename $y$ to $x$ and you get the conclusion in the video.

Answer (score 0):

One is a function of $x$, the other a function of $y$. If either has terms of positive degree, there's an $x$ or a $y$ lying about on that side that cannot be matched on the other. So both must be (the same) constant.